# how to add datagridview control to a radiobutton in the place of radiobuttonText in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a datagridview control in the place of radiobutton text.The output should be like this

Circle  DatagridviewControl

for that i written the code like this

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.Columns.Add("column1", "id");
dgv.Columns.Add("column2", "name");
dgv.Rows.Add(1, "Anusha");
dgv.Rows.Add(2, "Anu");
rd.Controls.Add(dgv);
rd.AutoSize = true;
dgv.AutoSize = true;
```

But it is not displaying properly.
Please help me how to achieve the output i am fresher to the winforms

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just position them correctly in the designer. Why does the DGV have to be inside the radio button like that? Unless I am misunderstanding it sounds like you're making it over-complicated.

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand why you want to do this. But if you really need it, just set left margin of DataGridView to some value,say 20. and then add this value to the width of RadioButton. don't forget to set radiobutton's autosize property to false.

```
`rd.AutoSize = false;
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.Columns.Add("column1", "id");
dgv.Columns.Add("column2", "name");
dgv.Rows.Add(1, "Anusha");
dgv.Rows.Add(2, "Anu");
dgv.Left = 20;          // adding the left margin
rd.Controls.Add(dgv);
rd.Height = dgv.Height;
rd.Width = dgv.Width + 20;  //adding same margin to the radio button width`
```